# C++ | Get the last value in list

Tags: c++, list

I have list of items (Item class)
and I would like to get the last value of list, and it's show me stupid error when I run the program (The error is in runtime and no compiler error)

this is the code:

```
int id = 1;
if(items.size() > 0)
    id = items.end()->getID() + 1;
```

items is the list variable and getID() is a function of Item class and its' which return int

the error is "list iterator not dereferencable"

Thanks for help guys ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`items.end()`, and other end-of-container iterators (e.g. `items.rend()`) point to one past the end of the list.  Try `items.back()->getID() + 1;`.

Answer (score 6):

[std::list::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container, This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in *undefined behavior*.

You could use [std::list::back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back) or reverse iterator [std::list::rbegin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin)

try:

```
items.back()->getID() +1;
(*items.rbegin())->getID() +1;
```